# Where with different conditions

Tags: sql

I have a table and want perform the following using `where`. I want to select all rows which have `NUM_ORDERS = 1` where `CHANNEL_ID in (1,2,3,4)` and in addition all rows where `NUM_ORDERS > 1` and `CHANNEL_ID in (1,2,3)`. How can I combine both conditions?

Thanks for help.

Comment: then write your query as you mentioned

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following SQL query should do it. Note that the parentheses I used in the where clause are not necessary due to operator precedence.

```
 SELECT *
    FROM [put_your_table_here]
    WHERE (NUM_ORDERS = 1 AND CHANNEL_ID IN (1,2,3,4)) OR (NUM_ORDERS > 1 AND CHANNEL_ID IN (1,2,3))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `UNION` which combines the results of query #1 and query #2.

```
select * from [table] where NUM_ORDERS = 1 AND CHANNEL_ID in (1,2,3,4) 
UNION
select * from [table] where NUM_ORDERS > 1 AND CHANNEL_ID in (1,2,3);
```

The `UNION` operator selects only distinct values by default. To allow duplicate values, use `UNION ALL`:

```
select * from [table] where NUM_ORDERS = 1 AND CHANNEL_ID in (1,2,3,4) 
UNION ALL
select * from [table] where NUM_ORDERS > 1 AND CHANNEL_ID in (1,2,3);
```

Another better solution is to use an `OR` clause like this;

```
SELECT * from [table] where (NUM_ORDERS = 1 AND CHANNEL_ID in (1,2,3,4)) or (NUM_ORDERS > 1 and CHANNEL_ID in (1,2,3));
```

Answer (score 3):

You have a few options:

Use OR:

```
SELECT...
WHERE (NUM_ORDERS = 1 AND CHANNEL_ID in (1,2,3,4))
OR
(NUM_ORDERS > 1 and CHANNEL_ID in (1,2,3))
```

Alternatively, union the two:

```
SELECT...
WHERE NUM_ORDERS = 1 AND CHANNEL_ID in (1,2,3,4)
UNION
SELECT...
WHERE NUM_ORDERS > 1 and CHANNEL_ID in (1,2,3)
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableName
WHERE (NUM_ORDERS = 1 AND CHANNEL_ID IN (1,2,3,4))
OR (NUM_ORDERS > 1 AND CHANNEL_ID IN (1,2,3))
```